# Change function for dropdown not being hit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownList("SalesChannelId", Model.SalesChannels, @AuctionControllerResource.SelectSalesChannel, new { id="salesChannel", required = "required" })
```

I have the following Javascript

```
$('#salesChannel').change(function() {
    var selectedSalesChannel = $("#salesChannel").val();
    var seenSalesChannel = $("#seenSalesChannelId").val();
    if (selectedSalesChannel == seenSalesChannel) {
        $("#remarketingSiteList").show();
    } else {
        $("#remarketingSiteList").hide();
    }
});
```

But for some reason this code never gets hit when I change the value in the dropdown.  I put a breakpoint in it in Firebug but no joy.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have selected wrong `Id`

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#SalesChannelId').change(function() {
    var selectedSalesChannel = $("#SalesChannelId").val();
    var seenSalesChannel = $("#seenSalesChannelId").val();
    if (selectedSalesChannel == seenSalesChannel) {
        $("#remarketingSiteList").show();
    } else {
        $("#remarketingSiteList").hide();
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$("#SalesChannelId").change
```

instead of

```
$('#salesChannel').change
```

because the id generated is *SalesChannelId* as specified in the helper func

```
@Html.DropDownList("SalesChannelId"
```